# How to solve such equations: $z^4 = -4$, $z \in \mathbb{C}$?

Tags: complex-numbers, radicals

I have the following task:

> Compute in each case all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $z^4 = -4$ and $z^3 = 5i$.

I do not know how to solve such eqautions fast. Do you have any idea of how to solve such equations?

And one further question:
The multiplication of two complex numbers is defined as

$$wz := (u+iv)(x+iy)=(ux-vy)+i(vx+uy)$$

But what if w or z would be defined in the following ways:

$$w = (u-iv)$$ or $$w = (-u+iv)$$

Would the formula change?

Thank you for helping me out guys

Comment: Use polar form. It's a lot more amenable to these types of calculations.

Comment: Do you know about the [$n$th root formula](https://socratic.org/questions/how-do-i-find-the-nth-root-of-a-complex-number)? Use Polar form of a complex number and apply it

Comment: I will look it up!

Comment: Isn’t the question impossible because the absolute value of z in the first case will be $4^{1/4}$ and in the second case it will be $5^{1/3}$

Comment: @Logik regardless from that it's essential that you know it in complex number problems like that, it's actually quite easier without it! Look at my answer

Comment: Are you asking for solving the exercise (i.e. the *system* of the two equations) or for solving them separately? It appears that there are disagreements concerning this issue present in the answers.

Comment: A common enough factorization is $$z^4+4=(z^4+4z^2+4)-4z^2=(z^2+2z+2)(z^2-2z+2)$$ reducing the first to two quadratic equations. Of course, I second the suggestion to familiarize yourself with complex $n$th roots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to keep in mind that taking roots are multi-valued in the complex plane. By the fundamental theorem of algebra every non-constant polynomial of degree $n$ has exactly $n$ in the complex plane when counted with multiplicity. This applies also for polynomials of the form $p(z)=z^n-c$ for some complex number $c\in\Bbb C^*$.

Of particular interest are the so-called [roots of unity](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RootofUnity.html) which are the roots of polynomials of the form $p(z)=z^n-1$. Solutions to the equation $z^n-1=0$ are called the $n^\text{th}$ roots of unity. Using polar coordinates we find that these are of the form $\zeta_n^k=\exp\left(k\frac{2\pi}n\right)$ for $k=0,...,n-1$.

Now, given an equation of the form $z^n-c=0$ we shall write $c$ as $c=r\exp(i\theta)$ where $r=|c|$ and $\theta=\arg c\in[0,2\pi)$. Then we can conclude that $z=r^\frac1n\exp \left(i\frac\theta n\right)$. But wait; there is more. In fact, every $z_k=r^\frac1n\exp \left(i\frac\theta n\right)\zeta_n^k$, $k=0,\dots,n-1$, is a solution too! We can express the general solution(s) therefore in the following manner
$$z_k=r^\frac1n\exp\left(i\frac{\theta+2\pi k}n\right),\,k=0,\dots,n-1$$
Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

For solving these equations, you can use exponential coordinates: write both $z$ as $\rho e^{i\theta}$ with $\rho\in(0,+\infty)$ and $\theta\in(-\pi,\pi]$ (treat $z=0$ as a special case, checking explicitly if it is a solution or not) and $w=\rho_w e^{i\theta_w}$. Then the equation $z^n=w$ rewrites as

$$\rho^ne^{in\theta}=\rho_we^{i\theta_w},$$

leading to the system of equations

$$\left\{\begin{array}{c}
\rho^n=\rho_w\\
n\theta=\theta_w\,[2\pi]
\end{array}\right.
\iff
\left\{\begin{array}{c}
\rho=\sqrt[n]{\rho_w}\\
\theta=\frac{\theta_w}{n}\,[\frac{2\pi}{n}]
\end{array}\right.,$$

where $\rho$ is now explicit and you still have to find the $\theta$ checking that.

For example, in your first case $z^4=-4=4e^{i\pi}$, you should find $\rho=\sqrt[4]{4}$ and $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}\,[\frac{\pi}{2}]$, which leads to $\theta\in\{\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{3\pi}{4},\frac{-\pi}{4},\frac{-3\pi}{4}\}$ if you use the info $\theta\in(-\pi,\pi]$.

Answer (score 0):

$$z^3=5i \implies z^4=5zi \implies -4=5zi \iff z=-4/5i=\frac{4}{5}i$$
But substituting $z$ back in the equations concludes there're no solutions.

Comment: You beat me to it by a few seconds! :) (+1)

Comment: @FranklinPezzutiDyer Yea! That was fun! But yours looks a bit more elegant :)